# how to prevent anonymous user to perform some actions via Firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to ensure that only non anonymous user that can create events in my Firestore database. but how to do that in Firestore security rules ?

```
 match /events/{eventID} {

      allow create: if isSignedIn() && if isNonAnonymous()


}

function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
}

function isNonAnonymous() {
    // what should I write in here ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API documentation for request.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth), you can use `request.auth.token.sign_in_provider`:

```
function isNonAnonymous() {
    return request.auth.token.sign_in_provider != 'anonymous';
}
```